# How to find singular form of a word using ruby?

Tags: ruby, string

I want to find singular form of words using ruby. Please suggest some ideas.

My ruby version 1.9.2

Comment: can you post your code what you had tried?

Comment: 'posts'.singularize #=>NoMethodError: undefined method `singularize' for "posts":String

Comment: you can install ActiveSupport (or ActiveRecord if you work with databases) by itself, no need to install Rails itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to install a Gem called [`ActiveSupport`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/activesupport/4.1.5/frames). Then do `require lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb`. Then use the method [`singularize`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/activesupport/4.1.5/ActiveSupport/Inflector#singularize-instance_method).

```
require 'lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb'

'posts'.singularize            # => "post"
'octopi'.singularize           # => "octopus"
```

Comment: Note that ActiveSupport is part of Rails. When you are already using Rails, you can just use the `singularize` method without installing and requiring any gems.

Comment: @p11y She is using *pure Ruby*.. Not Rails.

Comment: Yes, but other people might find this answer in the future and they might use Rails ;)